# c:forEach not working

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have a problem with a taglib method c:forEach. I want to get a List of languages from a servlet class and show it on a jsp page with c:forEach. But it is just showing nothing^^ an empty select tag.

The for each loop in the jsp file (i have taglib import and already tried without c:out):

```
...
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...
<c:forEach var="lang" items="${registrationServlet.inputLangs}">
  <option><c:out value="${lang}"></c:out></option>
</c:forEach>
```

My Servlet Class (it is a servlet because I have to do some form submitting stuff with it too):

```
...
// List of languages to choose from
List<String> inputLangs;
...
// Query the languages from the database
public List<String> getInputLangs() {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT Lang FROM country";
        ResultSet result = DbConnection.read(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            inputLangs.add(result.getString("lang"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get languages from DB.");
    }
    return inputLangs;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?^^

BTW. it works with pure java:

```
<%
RegistrationServlet reg = new RegistrationServlet();
for (String lang : reg.getInputLangs()) {
%>
  <option><%=lang%></option>
<%
}
%>
```

But as far as I know that's a no go in jsp files ;)

Comment: Well, since you don't really state what the issue is (error message, nothing is shown, something different than expected is shown, etc), i can't really tell you, but most probably you forgot to add the taglib import declaration at the top of your jsp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`${registrationServlet.inputLangs}` means:

- find an attribute named "registrationServlet" in the page scope
- if not found, find an attribute named "registrationServlet" in the request scope
- if not found, find an attribute named "registrationServlet" in the session scope
- if not found, find an attribute named "registrationServlet" in the application scope
- if found, call `getInputLangs()` on the found object

So, if you haven't stored any instance of `RegistrationServlet` in any scope, this expression will always evaluate to `null`. If you keep this design, the `doGet()` (or `doPost()`) method of your servlet should have the following line:

```
request.setAttribute("registrationServlet", this);
```

But it would be much cleaner to have

```
request.setAttribute("inputLangs", getInputLangs());
```

and, in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="lang" items="${inputLangs}">
```

Comment: Ok this is really helpfull, thx. So now it works, after I have submitted the first time. Obviously because then the doPost() is performed. Is there a method for the servlet wich is called onload of the jsp page?

Comment: No. In a well-designed MVC architecture, the servlet (controller) prepares all the data needed by the view (the JSP) and stores them in request attributes. Then it forwards to the view, and the view just gets what it has to display from the request attributes. This is what I suggest to do in the end of my answer.

Comment: Learned a lot, thank you. It's working now by calling the servlet first wich then forwards to the jsp:)!

Answer (score 0):

Have you got correct JSTL jar files on your class path?
In your case JSTL 1.1 JAR file in the /WEB-INF/lib

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info